# Python - Adding an AD user with "userPassword" and "userAccountControl" defined returns LDAP 53 - "Unwilling to perform"

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap

To preface, I've only been working with Python for about 5 months. I've been trying to write a program that will (eventually) do batch user creation. When formatted like it is below, it will successfully create a new user object, but the "userAccountControl" attribute will default to 546, ACCOUNTDISABLE | PASSWD_NOTREQD | NORMAL_ACCOUNT, and the value for "userPass" will appear plaintext as an octet string in the attributes editor for the object in AD. This program is using the ldap3 library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ldap3

```
class fromconfig:
    def __init__(self):
        Config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        Config.read("config.ini")
        self.serverip = Config.get('serverinfo', 'ip')
        self.basepath = Config.get('serverinfo', 'base')
        self.container = Config.get('serverinfo', 'container')
        self.dc1 = Config.get('serverinfo', 'dc1')
        self.dc2 = Config.get('serverinfo', 'dc2')
        self.ou = Config.get('serverinfo', 'ou')

def add_user(username, givenname, surname, userPrincipalName, SAMAccountName, userPassword):

    ad_server = Server(config.serverip, use_ssl=True, get_info=ALL) 

    ad_c = Connection(ad_server, user='domain\\user', password='password', authentication=NTLM)

    if ad_c.bind():
        ad_c.add('cn={},cn={},dc={},dc={}'.format(username, config.ou, config.dc1, config.dc2), ['person', 'user'], {'givenName': givenname, 'sn': surname, 'userPrincipalName': userPrincipalName, 'sAMAccountName': SAMAccountName, 'userPassword': userPassword})
        print(ad_c.result)

    ad_c.unbind()
```

I want to be able to define a 512 value for userAccountControl in the program, or otherwise successfully enable the account so that I don't have to go back through and uncheck "Account is disabled" in AD later. When I try to pass it, ad_c.result returns with an error 53. It's the same error I receive when I go in through AD and try to modify the attribute directly, or uncheck the disable account checkbox. The dialog for error 53 on the AD server says "The password does not meet length or complexity requirements", but the password I'm using for my testing is one that I've used on our AD in the past with no problems. So I think the issue has something to do with how userPassword is being stored rather than complexity or permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've figured it out, thanks to the example from [this](http://pythonexample.com/code/python-ldap3/). Defining a value for the "userPassword" key in the attributes dictionary will not work later when you go to manually enable the account. Instead, after adding the user account you can use the extended operations to unlock the account, modify the password, and then update the "userAccountControl" attribute with the desired value (In this case, I wanted 512: NORMAL_ACCOUNT).

It's extremely messy, but thankfully it works, so I'm now going to start refactoring the rest of the program so it doesn't look hideous

```
(continued from above)
    ad_c.add(...)
    ad_c.extend.microsoft.unlock_account(user='cn={},cn={},dc={},dc={}'.format(username, config.container, config.dc1, config.dc2))
    ad_c.extend.microsoft.modify_password(user='cn={},cn={},dc={},dc={}'.format(username, config.container, config.dc1, config.dc2), new_password=userpassword, old_password=None)
    changeUACattribute = {"userAccountControl": (MODIFY_REPLACE, [512])}
    ad_c.modify('cn={},cn={},dc={},dc={}'.format(username, config.container, config.dc1, config.dc2), changes=changeUACattribute)
```